# Issues in trimming a video with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, transcoding, webvideos

I have a .webm video captured through a web browser. Using ffmpeg, I want to trim it into its first 30s **without** re-encoding and quality degradation. But I have issues doing it and ffmpeg complains about it.

What is the problem? How can I address it?

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -to 30 -c copy out.webm
```

Error:

```
[webm @ 0000014ea3249a00] Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
```

Comment: WebRTC saves even H264 to webm which is not compatible. Save to mkv.

Comment: Would it work to save to .mp4? Any issues? It works for me though.

Comment: Depends on the codecs.

Comment: AVC video and Opus audio.

Comment: AVC is fine  Opus is not commonly accepted in MP4. Transcode audio to AAC.

Comment: I renamed it as .mp4 and Opus looks fine.